# Where to store Angular configurations

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some configurations and i need a place like .env in laravel or docker to choose my socket types ( using Pusher or Socket io ) or payment gateways and change them easily if needed.

I found out that environment.ts is not the place for those configurations and people recommended making static ts files including those configurations but this way i'm experiencing `error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"socket"' and '"pusher"' have no overlap.`  because i either choose pusher or socket and all of my conditions with either return true or false in each compile and angular is not allowing that.

Comment: Enviroment files are fine for static configs. Do you have runtime conditions that determine either one or the other value?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes we have similar services for push notification and payment gateways and if they have issue we switch to another one.
i read some articles saying not to treat environment.ts as an env file and i guess by that they meant not storing critical passwords or settings.
so its okay if i store these service switch configurations there ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to switch. If these are more like feature flags, the environment file isn’t suitable as you’ll have to rebuild your app.. I need to understand your use case better..

Comment: @MikeOne We recently developed socket io on our backend but we don't know its behavior under pressure of high number of users so instead of replacing currently used push notification service ( Pusher ) with socket_io i want to set a flag in configuration file so i can change and rebuild project if something goes wrong in future.
if(Env.('enabled_socket') == 'socket_id') load socket_io and use that ..
if(Env.('enabled_socket') == 'pusher') load pusher and use that ..

Comment: I'd suggest using a config table in the database. Setup the different options in code and compare to the query from the database which can easily be set at runtime (either directly in the db or e.g. using an admin panel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment.ts is the best way you can do it although you can write variables in environment.ts for develop mode in local and write variables in environment.prod.ts for production.